# Force exerted on vehicle when hitting an object

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration, collision

How can i calculate force that is exerted on a vehicle when it hits an object?

Vehicle speed is 40 km/h, mass is 1500kg
Object is standing still (speed is 0 km/h), object mass is 11kg.

Now this vehicle is hitting the object at 40 km/h. How much force does the 11 kg object exerted on the vehicle?

Note: Object is not stuck on the ground, when it gets hit by the vehicle it will start to move it. Imagine the object as an pedestrian.

Comment: This question does not have a single answer. It all depends on the specifics of the collision: under what angle is the pedestrian hit? Does any material deform? You can give numbers from experience, but you can't calculate this or at least not very accurately

Comment: Hi, i understand that there are many variables that need to take into consideration. For simplicity lets say the material doesnt deform. Both are absolutely rigid. And collison happens at 0 degrees. Meaning straight into the center of the bumper.

Comment: If the vehicle and the object both are "absolutely rigid," then the force between them will be infinite for an infinitesimal amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

From conservation of momentum you can calculate the [impulse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_(physics)) in this collision, but not the force itself. You would need more information on how the vehicle or the object/pedestrian deform or how long the collision takes to make an estimate of the force involved.

And if you say that neither object deforms, in the impulse you have the limit of vanishing time difference, thus the force diverges.

Comment: If vehicle hits the object, then after some time the object should have the same speed as the vehicle because the vehicle isnt stopping, right? But just the maximum force it exerts when object velocity is 0 and vehicle is 40 kmh. I'm bad at physics and have never calculated these things. Impulse seems even more complicated.

Comment: If you struggle with impulse, try to think of it in terms of acceleration: The force exerted is proportional to the acceleration (by Newton's laws), and the acceleration is the change of velocity per time. If the time interval you are changing the velocity in is of zero length, the acceleration is infinite and thus the force is infinite.